# Why Can I not view my React HomePage component in my development server (React-Router)(Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

I cannot view my homepage when I put it in the browser as http://localhost:3000/#/HomePage - all I can see is my Header and Footer components whereas I should see my Sidebar component that I am building for it in the homepage. Before I put the sidebar component in there was just writing in <h1? tags but that didn't display on the page either so it is not a problem with sidebar component.

I am using ReactRouter and Firebase authentication so I think the problem might be that because im not authenticated it wont show me the homepage which is only viewable by authorised users. However I cannot test this as I can't get the firebase authentication to work! I receive this error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' firebase-app.js:1'.

However I hope the above is not the problem because surely in my development server on localhost:3000 I should be able to access any page?

### Below is all relevant code for this please tell me if I am missing any important files or code snippets!

App/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter, Route, link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import { withAuthentication } from '../Session';


import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LandingPage from '../Landing';
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp';
import SignInPage from '../SignIn';
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget';
import HomePage from '../Home';
import AccountPage from '../Account';
import AdminPage from '../Admin';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session';
import Footer from '../Footer';






const App = () => (

  <HashRouter>
    <Container className="p-0" fluid={true}>
      <Navigation />
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING} component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomePage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} component={AdminPage} />
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  </HashRouter>
);

    


export default withAuthentication(App);
```

Navigation/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import styled from 'styled-components';
 
import SignOutButton from '../SignOut';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const Navigation = () => (
  <div>
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      {authUser => authUser ? <NavigationAuth /> : <NavigationNonAuth />}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  </div>);

const NavigationAuth = () => (
  <Container className="p-0" fluid={true}>
    <Navbar className="footer-middle" bg="transparent" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand>Job Tracker</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="navbar-toggle"/>
      <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-toggle">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <Link className="nav-link" to={ROUTES.LANDING}>Landing</Link>
          <Link className="nav-link" to={ROUTES.HOME}>Home</Link>
          <Link className="nav-link" to={ROUTES.ACCOUNT}>Account</Link>
          <SignOutButton />
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </Container>

);

const NavigationNonAuth = () => {
    return(

      <Container className="p-0" fluid={true}>
        <Navbar className="footer-middle" bg="dark" variant="light" expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand>Job Tracker</Navbar.Brand>

          <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="navbar-toggle"/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-toggle">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <Link className="nav-link" to={ROUTES.LANDING}>Landing</Link>
              <Link className="nav-link" to={ROUTES.SIGN_IN}>Sign IN</Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </Container>
    );
  }
export default Navigation;

const HeaderContainer = styled.footer`
    .footer-middle {
        background: #343a40;
        padding-top: 20rem;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 200px;
    }


    .footer-bottom {
        padding-top: 3rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;


    }

    ul li a {
        color: rgba(109, 109, 109);
    }

    ul li a:hover {
        color: rgba(172, 172, 172);
    }

`;
```

Home/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import { withAuthorization } from '../Session';
import  Sidebar  from '../Sidebar';

const HomePage = () => (
    <div>
        <Sidebar/>
    </div>
);

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(condition)(HomePage);
```

Session/WithAuthorization.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';

import AuthUserContext from './context';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
 
const withAuthorization = condition => Component => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
          this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
              authUser => {
                  if (!condition(authUser)) {
                      this.props.history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
                  }
              },
          );
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          this.listener();
      }


    render() {
      return(
          <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
              {authUser => condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null }
          </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  }
 
  return compose(
      withRouter,
      withFirebase,
    )(WithAuthorization);
};
 
export default withAuthorization;
```

I am not sure if the WithAuthentication.js file is needed but I will paste the context.js and index.js files from the session folder as they deal with session handling which might be the issue.

Session/index.js:

```
import AuthUserContext from './context';
import withAuthentication from './WithAuthentication';
import withAuthorization from './WithAuthorization';
 
export { AuthUserContext, withAuthentication, withAuthorization };
```

Session/context.js:

````
import React from 'react';
 
const AuthUserContext = React.createContext(null);
 
export default AuthUserContext;
```Re
````